# VBA unique formula with variable

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm having a really hard time setting the correct formula in VBA to output a list of unique values in a list.

```
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=UNIQUE(RC[-1]:" & lastRow & ")"
```

Pretty simple what I'm trying to do. Just use the range from cell A1 to the last row in the that column and push it to the unique formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A1 notation:

```
Range("B1").Formula2 = "=UNIQUE(A1:A" & lastRow & ")"
```

R1C1 notation:

```
Range("B1").Formula2R1C1 = "=UNIQUE(RC[-1]:R[" & lastRow & "]C[-1])"
```

Comment: BigBen, I tried that. The VBA script runs clean however the cell in B2 is thrown a #NAME? error. And the formula in the cell is =UNIQUE('A1':'A10')... Not sure how to get rid of the apostrophes

Comment: Second formula worked. First formula was getting thrown the error as mentioned above. Thanks!

Comment: Note that you need `.Formula2` and not `.Formula2R1C1` for the A1 notation example.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. You're right. Didn't understand the difference until now. Thanks for pointing that out.